# Can I configure my truffle project to use an .ipc endpoint file instead of an ethereum RPC listener?

Tags: ethereum, truffle, go-ethereum

I'm working on a project that uses truffle framework and want to test my code on a private ethereum network. When I run `truffle console`, it connects to the network specified in truffle.js, like this:

```
module.exports = {
  networks: {
    development: {
      host: "localhost",
      port: 8545,
      network_id: "*" // Match any network id
    }
  }
};
```

Is there a syntax that I can use to point truffle to a geth.ipc file somewhere on the system, or is truffle limited to network endpoints?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By definition, the endpoint is a RPC listener, not a file.
You can use `geth` to create a testnet.
To use it, you need to use it as an endpoint.

See the configuration options of `geth` to specify the port if it's not connecting right away.

`testrpc` is also allowing you to create a testnetwork (8535 is the default port).